# Migrate for Anthos not supporting Nested Virtualization workload migration to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to migrate my Nested Virtualization environment to gcloud using Migrate for Anthos. But migrate was not happened properly i got some issue on migration. Below issue i am facing while migrating my nested virtualization VM,

Error logs:
{​​​​​host.libvirt-bin.service] internal error: QEMU / QMP failed: Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM
[host.libvirt-bin.service] Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/kvm-spice: internal error: QEMU / QMP failed: Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM
[host.libvirt-bin.service] unsupported configuration
libvirtd[217]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/kvm: internal error: QEMU / QMP failed: Could not access KVM kernel module failed to initialize KVM

Please help me to resolve this issue and let me know anything logs needed.
Thanks in advance!....

Comment: Can you post the output of this command? 
`grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Running above command on my Nested Virtualization environment vm. root@opennebula-instance:~# grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo
0

Comment: do i need to run this command on migrated environment?

Comment: Yes, and a 0 return code as is your case means nested virtualization is not enabled. Could you try creating a new disk (that is a clone of the existing disk) with the special flag required for nested virt and then swapping the disk in the VM? See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#enablenestedvirt